# How to add custom commands/programs to run from windows File Explorer?

Tags: python, windows, explorer

There are custom commands that can be run from the file explorer address bar. For example, we can use `cmd` to open command prompt with the folder path as the current working directory. We can also use `code .` to open VS Code with the current folder open. I am creating an application, that could be run by giving a custom command from the file explorer address bar. I also need the current open folder path (from which directory the command was run from), to run certain operations. How can we achieve this?

`

I have tried creating a shortcut of a small python script which i converted to .exe, pasting it in C:\Windows folder to create my own run command that can run from the address bar, but it only returns the location of the .exe file. Below is the program i wrote.

```py
import os

with open("S:\\Coding\\Python\\file-sorter\\New folder\\dist\\log.txt","w") as o:
    o.write(os.popen('pwd').read())
```

I just want a method to create a custom command that can be run from the address bar of the file explorer, and can return the path of the open folder it is run from. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you "convert it to exe"? (Renaming is not converting.)

Comment: But, anyway, wouldn't it be easier to simply [add it to the context menu of directories](https://superuser.com/questions/419238/how-do-you-add-an-item-to-the-context-menu-of-a-folder)? (Like "Open in PowerShell", etc. does it)

Answer (score 0):

This script adds its directory to the environment path, which allows it to run from the navigation bar in the Explorer, or from the console, this code was taken from [Kieran Wood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840426/13253010):

```py
import ctypes  # Allows interface with low-level C API's
import os
import winreg  # Allows access to the windows registry


# dummy function, make a .bat file to run the current script
# in practice, replace this function with whatever command you need to run
def AddExecutable(exeName: str):
    with open(f"{exeName}.bat", "w") as f:
        f.write(f"python {__file__}")

# Add the script directory to the enviroment path variable if it doesn't exists
def SetupEnviroment(exeName: str):
    """Add the script to system path if not exists"""
    scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    
    with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as root: # Get the current user registry
        with winreg.OpenKey(root, "Environment", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as key: # Go to the environment key
            existing_path_value: str = winreg.EnumValue(key, 3)[1] # Grab the current path value

            # don't add to the enviroment path if it already exists
            for path in existing_path_value.split(";"):
                if path == scriptDir: return
            
            AddExecutable(exeName)

            # add a comma to the path if it doesn't end with a comma
            if existing_path_value[-1] != ";":
                existing_path_value += ";"
            
            new_path_value = existing_path_value + scriptDir + ";" # Takes the current path value and appends the new program path
            winreg.SetValueEx(key, "PATH", 0, winreg.REG_EXPAND_SZ, new_path_value) # Updated the path with the updated path

        # Tell other processes to update their environment
        HWND_BROADCAST = 0xFFFF
        WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002
        result = ctypes.c_long()
        SendMessageTimeoutW = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageTimeoutW
        SendMessageTimeoutW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, u"Environment", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, ctypes.byref(result),) 
        
    
SetupEnviroment("foo")

print(f"I'm running in {os.getcwd()}")
os.system("pause")
```

It will check if the script directory exists in the environment path, if not, it will create a .bat file which will run itself, then add its directory to the environment path. You'll need to replace the `AddExecutable` to fit your needs.

When it's executed from the Explorer, its working directory will be the Explorer's current directory.